# PHP - array key within array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this:

```
$arr = array(
  'id'     => 'app.settings.value.id',
  'title'  => 'app.settings.value.title',
  'user'   => 'app.settings.value.user'
);
```

I want to remove '.id', '.title' and '.user' in the array values. I want to insert the key of this array at the end of the value. I know, that I can get an array key by passing an array and a value to 'array_search', but I want the key within this one array definition - at the end of it's value. Is this possible?

Comment: Yoru question is unclear. You want to turn `array('id' => 'app.settings.value')` into `array('id' => 'app.settings.value.id')` by adding the key to the end of the value pair?

Comment: Yes, " I want to insert the key of this array at the end of the value". So I want to add this 'id', 'title' and 'user' at the end of the array value, which I would like to set to 'app.settings.value.', because I don't want to repeat this already existing key and I think it's a more dynamic solution. I didn't think it's unclear, because I wrote, that I want to add the key (which is 'id', 'title' and 'user) at the end of the array value (which is 'app.settings.value.', where it doesn't matter, what the array value is).

Comment: In your example it looks like 'id', 'title', and 'user' are already at the ends of the array values. If this is not the case, can you edit the question to show both what the array currently looks like and what you are trying to turn it into?

Comment: @J.Wenston If you write an example of desired input/output array, your question is certainly more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this, but I guess it's simple and works:

```
$arr = array(
  'id'     => 'app.settings.value',
  'title'  => 'app.settings.value',
  'user'   => 'app.settings.value'
);

$result = array();
foreach ($arr AS $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = $value . '.' . $key;
}
```

You're storing `app.settings.value` which is the same for all array items, so personally I'd prefer:

```
$arr = array(
  'id',
  'title',
  'user'
);

function prepend_key($key)
{
    return 'app.settings.value.' . $key;
}

$result = array_map('prepend_key', $arr);
```

With `$result` containing:

```
array(
  'app.settings.value.id',
  'app.settings.value.title',
  'app.settings.value.user'
);
```

At the end of the day, either works :)

Comment: What don't you like about it?

Comment: Updated answer to show, I guess it doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things.